# Share extension app store upload issue

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

Hello fellow developers,

I'm uploading an app with share extension, extension should only accept images.

For some reason when I'm uploading app for beta testing i get an warning as  below.

> No values under NSExtensionActivationRule in bundle APPNAME.app/PlugIns/ShareOnAPPNAME.appex appear to trigger activation.

Also I got email saying below

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "APPNAME". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Unreachable Activation - No values under NSExtensionActivationRule in bundle APPNAME.app/PlugIns/ShareOnAPPNAME.appex appear to trigger activation.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

My plist file in extension target looks like this...I tried adding all support key with value 0 except image and only image key with value 1...but warning persists...

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key> NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount </key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>ShareOnAPPNAMEVC</string>
</dict>
```

Also App shows sharing option to each and every type i.e. movies, text, webpage etc. along with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I got it working, issue was copy pasted rule NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount from developer side caused blank spaces in plist :( check below.

```
<key> NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount </key>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use this:

```
<key>NSExtension</key> 
<dict> 
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key> 
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key> 
        <dict> 
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key> 
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string> 
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>              
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>                                              
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key> 
            <false/> 
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key> 
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict> 
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```